# angular 4 Expression Changed After It Has Been Checked Error in app.component.ts

Tags: angular

I get the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.` error after I log out somewhere inside the app, and the `front` getter in `app.component.ts` changes in its view.

Also, if I enable production mode, the error does not appear! It all works regardless, but I would like not to see the error.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12" [class.space]="!front">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
get front() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("user") === "\"admin\"") {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: make use of `setTimeout()`

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't wrap the whole thing inside the getter in a timeout.

Comment: Does this work :  "\"admin\"" ? seems incorrect

Answer (score -1):

put the whole code inside a `setTimeout` like this

```
get front() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user") === "\"admin\"") {
      resolve(false);
    }
    resolve(true);
  }, 200));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't return value for the getter

Comment: @yurzui ya it dosent you need to explicitly assign a variable to it and then use it in the getter

Comment: I cannot use `let` inside a component first of all. Second, should I not have a getter but just a plain property? This does not work just like so, can you give the whole thing?

Comment: I have the `value` inside the class itself and then the `setTimeout` inside `ngOnInit` but it does not work as expected if that is what you meant?

Comment: if you have value inside calss just use this.value then and assign the same and then retunr value in the getter

Comment: I cannot use `setTimeout` inside the component just like so, it has to be inside some kind of a method. I put it in `ngOnInit` and then tried using  `this.value` inside the getter but it is not correct, what it gets the first time is what stays as the `value` value, it does not change on logging in and out.

Comment: if you meant it like so it does not work, it is always true: `get front() {
        let value = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (localStorage.getItem("user") === "\"admin\"") {
            value = false;
          }
        },0);
        return value;
    }`

Comment: updated the ansswer check , or better use a callback

Comment: this will always return `true`

Comment: we will need to return a promise , as we cannot use callbacks here , better is to return a promise,updated @yurzui

Comment: same thing, again it is always true.